# Create React App cannot find tests

Tags: regex, reactjs, testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I recently started a new project using create-react-app. I moved the `App.test.js` from outside the `/src` folder into a root level `/tests` folder so my folder structure looks like this now:

```
> node_modules
> public
> src
   ...
   App.js
> tests
   App.test.js
...
```

And here's the entire App.test.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "../src/App";

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

So when I try `npm run test`, no tests get executed. It says that no tests can be found. How can I get create-react-app to recognize the new `/tests` folder as the new location for all tests and run them?

Answer (score 11):

From [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#running-tests) docs:

> Filename Conventions
>   Jest will look for test files with any of the following popular naming conventions:
>
> Files with .js suffix in `__tests__` folders. Files with .test.js
>   suffix. Files with .spec.js suffix. The .test.js / .spec.js files (or
>   the `__tests__` folders) can be located at any depth under the src top
>   level folder.
>
> We recommend to put the test files (or `__tests__` folders) next to the
>   code they are testing so that relative imports appear shorter. For
>   example, if App.test.js and App.js are in the same folder, the test
>   just needs to `import App from './App'` instead of a long relative path.
>   Colocation also helps find tests more quickly in larger projects.

Hope it helps you

Comment: I was bitten by the same problem, and the cause was that my `__tests__` folder (like your `tests` folder) was a peer to `src`. But, when I read the docs carefully, I realized that `__tests__` had to be nested inside the `src` folder for the tests to be found.  So you'll need to rename (to `__tests__`) and move (to inside `src`) your folder for it to be found.