# Can either run React App or tests for it with babel-jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I am trying to set up tests for the existing React app. We are using `React 16.8.13`
After some struggle I've made it work. For that I had to install `jest 24.9.0` and `babel-jest 24.9.0`. The tests run fine and I am getting a coverage report. However when I run `yarn start` I am getting an error:

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-jest": "23.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-jest was detected higher up in the tree:

  /<Path to my App>/node_modules/babel-jest (version: 24.9.0)
```

removing both`jest` and `babel-jest` from `devDependencies` fixes the issue, but now running `yarn test` gives me an error:

```
No tests found
In /<Path to my App>
  32 files checked.
  testMatch:  - 32 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 32 matches
  testRegex: (\/tests\/.*\.test)\.[jt]sx?$ - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

What do I need to do to have both app and tests runnable?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `No tests found`, it looks like your tests might not be in the right folder. They should be in a folder in `src` called `__tests__` and have a `test.js` or `spec.js` suffix.

See this answer for more info: [Create React App cannot find tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602402/create-react-app-cannot-find-tests)

Comment: My tests are in `tests` folder, rather than in `__tests__`. I am using `testRegex: (\/tests\/.*\.test)\.[jt]sx?$` to overwrite the defaults which are the ones you mention. If I remove `testRegex` from jest.config, the test are in fact found but anywhere in the app directory not as I wanted in just one folder. So apparently this configuration works with version 24.9 but not with 23.6 by the looks of it.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest `create-react-app`? Looks like it uses jest `24.9.0` https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/package.json#L33

Comment: I was wrong about `testRegex` not working. It does work, it does look for test files inside my `tests` directory, however it seems like it doesn't recognize TypeScript files as test files. As soon as I rename my `.test.tsx` file to `.test.js` or `.test.jsx` it finds it, but if it's a `.test.tsx` it says 0 matches. Any ideas? Maybe I need to add something to tell it to recognize TypeScript?

Comment: Strange, that regex looks like it should match `.test.tsx`. You might need to do set up the jest config like this https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/testing/jest.html - although I think Create React App might restrict what you can do in the jest config...